# Convert grouped rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this in my SQL Server database:

```
o_owner period                  price
-------------------------------------
00035   2016-08-05$$$2016-08-12 10
00035   2016-08-13$$$2016-08-19 20
00035   2016-08-20$$$2016-08-26 30
00036   2016-08-05$$$2016-08-12 11
00036   2016-08-13$$$2016-08-19 12
00036   2016-08-20$$$2016-08-26 13
00037   2016-08-05$$$2016-08-12 21
00037   2016-08-13$$$2016-08-19 23
00037   2016-08-20$$$2016-08-26 29
```

And I need result like this

```
o_owner 2016-08-05$$$2016-08-12 2016-08-13$$$2016-08-19 2016-08-20$$$2016-08-26
--------------------------------------------------------------------
00035   10                      20                      30
00036   11                      12                      13
00037   21                      23                      29
```

I spent hours, using pivot, temp tables, etc  and still can't build it.

---

finally in fixed coloumn mode i can built it, still need solution for dynamic coloumn

```
select a.o_owner
,(select price from myTable where period='2016-08-05$$$2016-08-12' and   o_owner = a.o_owner) as "2016-08-05$$$2016-08-12"
,(select price from myTable where period='2016-08-13$$$2016-08-19' and o_owner = a.o_owner) as "2016-08-13$$$2016-08-19"
,(select price from myTable where period='2016-08-20$$$2016-08-26' and  o_owner = a.o_owner) as "2016-08-20$$$2016-08-26"
from myTable a
group by a.o_owner
```

i imagine to use looping to count 'period' and then rebuilt query and executed it something like

```
declare @sql as text
declare @sqlAdd as varchar(512)
@sqlAdd = --***looping here to count and built query for 'period' coloumn dynamically***
@sql = 'select a.o_owner' + 
@sqlAdd +
'from myTable a
group by a.o_owner'
execute(@sql)
```

anyone can help?

Comment: If a new period suddenly shows up in the table, do you expect another column in your result?

Comment: @jarlh yes it is Sir

Comment: i think it is depend on how may period fields would be.. this a pivot eventually

Comment: @reds i try with above data (forget the dynamic coloumn for period) but the pivot still doesn't works. could you please write the query pls?

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed columns, you can use case - something like :

```
   select o_owner, sum(p1) p1, sum(p2) p2, sum(p3) p3 from (
     select 
        o_owner,
        case when period = '2016-08-05$$$2016-08-12' then price end p1, 
        case when period = '2016-08-13$$$2016-08-19' then price end p2, 
        case when period = '2016-08-20$$$2016-08-26' then price end p3
     from mytable
   ) x
   group by o_owner
```

(I have used p1 - p3 as the period names to reduce typing)

Comment: hi @Ian thanks, but your query result 'price' as the most right coloumn instead of value in 'period'

Comment: oops- that was a pretty bad mistake - answer has been edited